primeNg Calendar Module does not expand parent container element
I am using PrimeNg as the UI library.
I have a splitter panel, where the left panel is some navigation item, and the right panel is some content.
I have 2 calendar modules near the end of the form, there are only 2 buttons below these calendar.
It looks ok, until when I click on the calendar module and the datepicker pops up, the botton half of it is not showing.
I checked the height of the html/body element, because there is not much content, the height is only 500, so it means the calendar module got cut off at the middle of the screen
I checked the p-datepicker class element is set to have position:absolute, this causes it to not expand the height of the parent elements.
Is there any good way around this / solution?
I can

set the container to have like height:90vh
use inline calendar instead
relocate the element to be away from end of form

but none of these seems a fool proof or elegant solution to me
screenshot:

